# Proving $d_ud_vf = d_vd_uf$ if $f$ is $C^2$ for any vectors $u,v$ using Clairauit's Theorem:

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, metric-spaces

I was wondering if a proof using Clairaut's theorem works. Here is my attempt; it looks right to me but I am not comfortable with differential calculus in Euclidean space at all still.

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^2$ function, and let $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be arbitrary vectors. We aim to prove that the mixed directional derivatives of $f$ satisfy the equality $d_ud_vf = d_vd_uf$. By Clairaut's Theorem, which states that the mixed partial derivatives of a $C^2$ function are continuous and commutative, we know that the order of differentiation does not matter for second derivatives. Thus, we can write:
$$ d_ud_vf(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n u_i v_j \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n u_i v_j \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j \partial x_i}(x) = d_vd_uf(x). $$

Therefore, we conclude that $d_ud_vf(x) = d_vd_uf(x)$ for any $C^2$ function $f$ and for any vectors $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I think it’s fine, I don’t see an issue. The summations are finite so those are not cause for concern.